# MS Access (VBA) - DoCmd.OpenQuery (but make the query Pop up)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form which is Modal and Pop up (and then additional code to hide the background) so the client only sees the form.

On this form I have a button which uses the following code to run a query based on the keyword in a text box.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

Dim strsearch As String
Dim Task As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

strsearch = Me.Text13.Value
Task = "SELECT GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber, GrantInformation.GrantTitle, GrantInformation.StatusGeneral, GrantSummary.Summary "
Task = Task & "FROM GrantInformation LEFT JOIN GrantSummary ON GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber = GrantSummary.GrantRefNumber "
Task = Task & "WHERE (((GrantInformation.LeadJointFunder) = 'Global Challenges Research Fund')) Or (((GrantInformation.Call) = 'AMR large collab')) "
Task = Task & "GROUP BY GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber, GrantInformation.GrantTitle, GrantInformation.StatusGeneral, GrantSummary.Summary "
Task = Task & "HAVING (((GrantSummary.Summary) Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"")) OR (((GrantSummary.Summary) Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""));"

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(Task, dbOpenSnapshot)
With dbs
Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("tmpProductInfo", Task)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "tmpProductInfo"
.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpProductInfo"
End With
dbs.Close
qdf.Close

End Sub
```

This all works perfectly. However it shows the Access application and shows the query in there (I dont want them to see the Access application).

Is it possible when running:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "tmpProductInfo"
```

To make it pop up in its own window with VBA?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't use DoCmd.OpenQuery. Create a new form and open it instead of query, use SQL text as RecordSource, or even better use a query as RecordSource, which references to Text13 control directly

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines would be the answer, but that does seem a bit convoluted (especially as I am going to have another load of code haha). Are you saying you cant do it with a query, or you just suggest doing it with another form?   Thank you.

Comment: *have to FIND another load of code (wont let me edit my comment for some reason)

Comment: I'm suggesting using another form. DoCmd.OpenQuery opens query in Access query builder, so why you see Access window.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Back to the drawing board! :)

Comment: Another option, depending on your setup, is to dump the query results to an excel sheet that will pop up independently of MS Access. It is very simple (it is a single command) but it has disadvantages (mostly that users can get confused if other excel files are open and any potential conflicts if a user tries to open it more than once and of course that it requires Excel). Depending on what the users use the popup query for it may be a good solution.

Comment: I never thought of that, thank you SunKnight. I managed to get what I wanted through adding it all to a listbox with some code I found, so all resolved in the end :)